# Cors Error in simple request: Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, http, cors

I want to send a request from a dummy webpage to a web app (deployed on a server in the same sub net). The thing is that I can't use jQuery.

Only JS (doesn't work):

```
var $token;
var username = "user1";
var password = "123456";
var url = "http://192.168.110.35:8080/wwdf/api/login";
var data = {"username": username, "password": password};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    $token = xhr.responseText.access_token;
} else {
    console.log("Error: readyState = " + xhr.readyState + " | Status " + xhr.status);
}
};
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

JQuery (works):

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    username: username,
    password: password,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    },

    success: function (response) {
        token = response.access_token;
        $("#btn").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.110.35:8080/wwdf/api/login. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Network monitoring:

```
Response

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, content-type, x-auth-token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 29 Feb 2016 15:59:29 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headers

Request

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.168.110.35:8080
Origin:http://192.168.12.69
Referer:http://192.168.12.69/...
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help !

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your server to respond with `authorization` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header.  Right now, that header is only set to `accept, content-type, x-auth-token` by your server.  Or you need to remove the `Authorization` header from your JS example.  In the JS example you set it, but in JQuery you don't.  That's why you are getting different results.

Comment: @Fourat, if this answers your question, please accept it.  Others seem to be finding it helpful.